# Using the Regex OR operator to accommodate user input of "A" or "An"

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to validate a user input of either 'a' | 'an' which will satisfy the if statement. If it is not satisfied, the elif block will check to see if the second word is "about", if not "about", it will then check for "anyone". Unfortunately 'about' & "anyone" both start with the letters 'a' or 'an' so I needed to add a 'space' after the end of 'a' and 'an' to allow for Regex to detect the difference.

```
# Receive User input.
secrets = {}
secrets['text'] = request.GET.get('text')

regex_a = re.compile("(a|an)")
regex_about = re.compile('about')
regex_anyone = re.compile('anyone')

# Get second word from secrets[text]
secondword = secrets['text'].split()[1]
# If 2nd word is == 'a/an'
if regex_a.match(secondword):
    return HttpResponse("Text was (a) or (an)")

# Else if 2nd word is == about
elif regex_about.match(secondword):
    return HttpResponse("Second word was (about)")

elif regex_anyone.match(secondword):
    return HttpResponse("Second word was (anyone)")

else:
    return HttpResponse("Failed to interpret user input")
```

The current Regex `("(a|an)")` returns `Text was (a) or (an)` even when the user inputs "about" or "anyone" as the second word, this is expected.

So I also tried `("(a\s|an\s)")` which returns `Failed to interpret user input` when the input for the second word is 'a' or 'an'. However it returns the correct response for 'about' & 'anyone'. Which is really confusing...

I then also tried `("(a_|an_)")` which returns the same results as the previous test.

Apart from these three tests I have attempted many others, but will not list them here as there are far to many.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
regex_a = re.compile("(a|an)$")
```

That way you are telling the regex that the string needs to end right there for a match.

The regex `("(a\s|an\s)")` would not work never because it expects the substrings `'a '` and `'an '` to match, and the problem is that the `split()` in `secondword = secrets['text'].split()[1]` returns whitespace-trimmed strings.

Comment: Thanks! This was the simplest answer and worked perfectly without the need for any adjustments to my current code structure. :D

Answer (score 5):

Use this :

```
(a\b|an\b)
```

the `\b` is a word boundary, matching the end of the word.

[Demo here](http://regexr.com/3at5p). Welcome on Stack Overflow! Take the site tour in the Help section if you haven't already! :-)

Comment: For some reason this didn't work for me. I received `Failed to interpret user input` when the user input was equal to 'a' or 'an'.

Comment: @liamm , did you escape the slashes? If not, try `(a\\b|an\\b)` :-)

Comment: Sorry I really should have remembered to escape the slashes. After testing I can confirm this also works!

Comment: Heh, we all forget that ;-) Cheers!

Comment: @liamm and @Docteur, you can use Python raw strings and forever forget of escaping slashes. That means `r'(a\b|an\b)'` is equal to `'(a\\b|an\\b)'` for RegEx purposes. Read more [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.match`:

```
pattern = "^(A|An)$|^((?!^A$|^An$)about)$|^((?!^((?!^A$|^An$)about)$)anyone)$"
m = re.match(pattern, secondword)

if m:
    print(m.groups())
```

Here is a breakdown of this expression:

```
^(A|An)$
```

This matches `"A"` or `"An"` as isolated words.  If that doesn't match, then it goes to the next case.

```
^((?!^A$|^An$)about)$
```

This matches the word `"about"`, but *only* if `"A"` or `"An"` do not occur as isolated words.  If this doesn't match, then it goes to the next case.

```
^((?!^((?!^A$|^An$)about)$)anyone)$
```

This matches the word `"anyone"`, but only if `"about"` as an isolated word (in the absence of `"A"` and `"An"`) does not occur.

You can test the regex [here](http://regexr.com/3at5s).

Comment: A regex this complicated could really benefit from some explanation.

Comment: What is the point of this regex? OP wants to be able to test, and using `elif`s with three regexes might be a tad slower but way more readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
sentence = "I am about to finish my Engineering and become an Engineer and a responsible person."
re.findall(r'(a|an)\s', sentence)
```

An extra space will consider it as separate word.

Comment: I am considering "a" and "an" come before any word only, as they are articles. So, it will extract correctly.